# Change proccess session

Tags: 14.04, process, session

Lets say I have a process which has session id 10030, Is there any way to remove the current process from this session and assign it to another? Or at least remove from this session? I've read this:

`The session's ID is the same as the pid of the process that created the session through the setsid() system call. That process is known as the session leader for that session group. All of that process's descendants are then members of that session unless they specifically remove themselves from it.`

But unfortunately I could not found how "`they specifically remove themselves from it`" can be done. Hope you can help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a one-time thing, here is a technique using `gdb` to attach to a running process:

Start a sample program. We will be changing `sleep`'s sid.

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ (echo;sleep 86400)&
[1] 23340
```

Here is our `sleep` process:

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ ps -efj -q 23342
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
spectras 23342 23340 23340 22112  0 14:50 pts/5    00:00:00 sleep 86400
```

Let's attach to it using `gdb`. Note this will pause the process.

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ gdb -p 23342
[lots of irrelevant text]
Attaching to process 23342
[more irrelevant text]

(gdb) p setsid()
$1 = 23342
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 23342] will be detached.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: /bin/sleep, process 23342
```

Let's see the result:

```
spectras@etherbee:~$ ps -efj -q 23342
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
spectras 23342 23340 23342 23342  0 14:50 ?        00:00:00 sleep 86400
```

Our `sleep` is now the process group leader of its own session.

Comment: Thank very much for response. But is there any way to do this programatically? I mean code(script) which can be run inside inside a proccess to change session id?

Comment: `gdb` supports a `-ex` option to feed it commands from script. Should not be too hard to automate.

Comment: you example above is the same as the proccess which is in session run `setsid` command in it and become session leader of another session right?

Comment: @user3503143> exactly. In fact we pause the process when we attach to it, we force it to run `setsid()` and unpause it when we detach. Thus it becomes session leader of a new session.